# Trouble understanding this voltage divider for a non-inverting Op Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I'm going through the Op Amp section in The Art of Electronics and I'm having trouble understanding their derivation of the gain for the following circuit:

[image]

So by the properties of Op Amps \$ v_A=v_{in} \$, now the way I understand this circuit is that since the potential at A is \$ v_{in}\$ and \$ R_1 \$ is connected to the ground there will be a current flowing through \$ R_1 \$ towards the ground. Since another property of Op Amps is that the current going into them is essentially 0 we know that this current must also pass through \$ R_2 \$ so we can find \$ v_{out}\$ and hence the gain by using \$ v_{out}=v_{in}+iR_2\$ where \$i=\frac{v_{in}}{R_1}\$.

However in the textbook, it is explained as "But \$v_a\$ comes from a voltage divider: \$v_a=\frac{v_{out}R_1}{R_1+R_2}\$", I'm just having trouble seeing why this is valid, this comes from current being \$i=\frac{v_{out}}{R_1+R_2}\$ and then going from the ground to point A through \$R_1\$, I suppose I am confused by the fact that this finds a different current through the resistors than my method and it still works.

Comment: Your equation for *i* in the first paragraph isn't correct. The one in the textbook is correct. All the current from the output to ground flows through R1 *and* R2, and there is no current into or out of A at all.

Comment: @EJP I actually believe my equation for \$i\$ in the first paragraph is still correct it's just that it's described in terms of \$v_{in}\$ instead of \$v_{out}\$, I think I get why now since when using the input voltage to find current it is just 1 series resistor and when using the output voltage it travels through both \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ and I suppose \$v_a\$ is in parallel with \$R_1\$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both solutions are equivalent. They just look different because one current is in terms of vin and the other in terms of vout.

If you substitute (from the gain) \$V_{in} = V_{out}\frac{R1}{R1+R2}\$ you get the equation in the book.

Comment: Craig - a short explanation in words: It is correct that the voltage at node A is (nearly) identical to Vin - however, the voltage at node A is not a source! Instead, this voltage is produced by Vout according to a simple voltage divider.